# How does a Publisher / Subscriber process actually work?

Tags: java, c#, observable, message-queue, publish-subscribe

In a process that uses a Publisher / Subscriber model, how does the subscriber actually know it has something that needs to be consumed?  I am looking for a better understanding of the inner workings of the processes so I can understand the broad concept.

Does it constantly poll and check if it needs to do something, or is there some other way that it picks up the requirement that it needs to process?

What ties the subscriber to know to pick up the event that it needs to be picking up?  How does it know when?

I am looking to really understand how their events are communicating with each other (so I can look past the top illusion of it just working, and understand the inner workings of it).

Comment: It depends on how you implement it. Usually, the subscriber registers with the publisher (hence "subscriber"), and the publisher pushes whatever it has to publish to all registered subscribers through a callback. The .NET standard interfaces are `IObservable`/`IObserver`.

Comment: Can you share an example showing how / where the subscriber registers to receive the data from the publisher? 
Does the subscriber have to have some centralized interface that is implemented so the Publisher knows what method to invoke when it has an item for the subscriber?